# Slicing a list advice

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm trying to slice a list in a certain way in Python. If I have a list that looks like this:

```
myList = ['hello.how.are.you', 'hello.how.are.they', 'hello.how.are.we']
```

Is there a way to slice it so that I can get everything after the last period for each element? So, I would want "you", "they", and "we".

Comment: Did you omit a bunch of quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done:

```
# Input data
myList = ["hello.how.are.you", "hello.how.are.they", "hello.how.are.we"]

# Define a function to operate on a string
def get_last_part(s):
    return s.split(".")[-1]

# Use a list comprehension to apply the function to each item
answer = [get_last_part(s) for s in myList]

# Sample output
>>> answer: ["you", "they", "we"]
```

A footnote for speed demons: Using `s.rpsilt(".", 1)[-1]` is even faster than `split()`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to slice the list directly that way; what you do is slice each element.

You can easily build a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) where you [`split`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) on the period and take the last element.

```
myList = ["hello.how.are.you", "hello.how.are.they", "hello.how.are.we"]
after_last_period = [s.split('.')[-1] for s in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[i.split('.')[-1] for i in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you omitted quotes around each list element, use a list comprehension and `str.split()`:

```
[x.split('.')[-1] for x in myList]
```